# How to exit game loop with several pygame events written in one line?

Tags: python, pygame

I apologize for the vague title, but essentially I want to exit a game loop in several different ways using pygame. 
Given the following code, I want to avoid writing "running = False" twice. A very minor thing I know, but I would like to write both "if" conditions in less lines with "and" and "or", if possible.

```
running = True
while running:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
pg.quit()
```

This is my first time asking a question, so please excuse me if this is too vague or just a dumb question. Thanks anyway in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal it to exit on either of those cases this would work:

```
running = True
while running:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT or  (e.type == pg.KEYDOWN and e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
            running = False

pg.quit()
```

You could shorten it even more using:

```
while True:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT or  (e.type == pg.KEYDOWN and e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
            break

pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some good old Boolean algebra, with parens for grouping!

I think this does the exact same thing, but you might want to double-check:

```py
while True:
    for e in pg.event.get():
        if e.type == pg.QUIT or (e.type == pg.KEYDOWN and e.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
            pg.quit()
```